# Cannot operate on a closed cursor in sqlite3 python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, cursor, jupyter-notebook

I've been following this 5 part tutorial from this YouTube playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDezJh0sC5CqXLKZTSKU1YNo

I'm using Jupyter notebook with Python with the following code:

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect("tutorial2.db")
c = conn.cursor()
```

Then I create several functions.

```
def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot (unix REAL, datestamp TEXT,
    keyword TEXT, value REAL)')

def data_entry():

    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES (145123542, '2016-01-03',
              'Python', 7)")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()

create_table()
data_entry()
```

It works fine the first time, and generates a db file in C:\Users\Michael
However, when I try to run only the create_table() function again, I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor.
```

Anyone able to help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to open connection again and create cursor to use it, or move the 'close' to another method

Comment: Yes because you explicitly close the cursor in data_entry. Why does this surprise you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit: You cannot run queries on closed cursors. Here it's even worse since you have also closed the connection at the first call of the `data_entry()` function.

I would advise on opening a cursor for each query, and then closing it after completing the query, and only closing the connection at the end of your script:

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect("tutorial2.db")

def create_table():
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuffToPlot (unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')
    c.close()

def data_entry():
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES (145123542, '2016-01-03', 'Python', 7)")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()


create_table()
data_entry()
```

By moving the `conn.close()` statement after you have completed all of your queries, and opening the cursors only when you need them, the error won't occur anymore.

**EDIT** : What is happening in your video is the following:

1. He first executes the whole script once.
2. He comments the line that creates the table.
3. He executes the whole script a second time.

I think you are probably entering the commands in a python interactive session, which is not equivalent to what he is doing in the video, because when he re-executes the script, a new connection and cursor are created, whereas if you're only trying to call the function again, the cursor and connection are already closed, which causes the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thundzz. I commented `#conn.commit()` and then also `#c.close()`, and ran the two functions again, but got the same error. Also, the video tutorial I'm following doesn't get any error as shown at 10:05 in his video. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-vsdfCBpsU&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDezJh0sC5CqXLKZTSKU1YNo`

Comment: Thanks Thundzz, your code worked. I'm a complete noob to sqlite3, much appreciated!